# Index outside of bounds of the array error while trying to convert Roman numbers to Integer in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, roman-numerals

I am trying to write a C# program that will convert Roman numbers to Integer.

I get index outside of bounds of the array error when I try short inputs.

When I try long input like = "MCMXIV" (it equals to 1994) I get exactly 1994 as result.

But when I try shorter input like "III", I get Index outside of bounds of the array error.

Can you check my code and tell me where did I make mistake? Thanks.

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.Write("Input:");
        string s = Console.ReadLine();
        int print = RomanToInt(s);
        
        Console.WriteLine($"Result is: {print}");
        
        static int RomanToInt(string s) 
        {    
            
                int [] decimalValues = new int[7]  { 1,  5, 10, 50, 100, 500, 1000};       
        
                int [] inputValues = new int[s.Length];
        
                for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
                {
                        if (s[i] == 'I')
                        {
                            inputValues[i] = decimalValues[0];
                        }
                        else if (s[i] == 'V')
                        {
                            inputValues[i] = decimalValues[1];
                        }
                        else if (s[i] == 'X')
                        {
                            inputValues[i] = decimalValues[2];
                        }
                        else if (s[i] == 'L')
                        {
                            inputValues[i] = decimalValues[3];
                        }
                        else if (s[i] == 'C')
                        {
                            inputValues[i] = decimalValues[4];
                        }
                        else if (s[i] == 'D')
                        {
                            inputValues[i] = decimalValues[5];
                        }
                        else if (s[i] == 'M')
                        {
                            inputValues[i] = decimalValues[6];
                        }
                }
        
       
                int [] inputValuesAfter = new int[s.Length];

                for (int i = 0; i < inputValues.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (inputValues[i] >= inputValues[i+1])
                    {
                        inputValuesAfter[i] = inputValues[i];
                    }
                    else if (inputValues[i] < inputValues[i+1])
                    {
                          inputValuesAfter[i] = inputValues[i+1] - inputValues[i];
                          i++;
                    }   
                }
            
                int result = 0;
        
                for (int i = 0; i < (inputValuesAfter.Length); i++)
                {
                    result += inputValuesAfter[i]; 
                }
             
                return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line gives the exception? What's the value of the indexer and the contents of the array when the exception is thrown?

Comment: Duplicate: [What is an IndexOutOfRangeException / ArgumentOutOfRangeException and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20940979/what-is-an-indexoutofrangeexception-argumentoutofrangeexception-and-how-do-i-f)

Comment: You increment the ‘for’ control variable’i’ inside the loop. Aside: you should learn about the ‘switch’ statement.

Comment: You are failing on line : "if (inputValues[i] >= inputValues[i + 1])"  When you enter "iii" as input is length 3.  So 'i' goes from 0 to 2 (length 3).  But you are indexing "i + 1".  So when 'i' is 2 then 'i + 1' is 3 which give the exception since the length of the array is 3 (0 to 2).  So either the for loop needs to be 0 to (inputValues.Length - 1) or you need to change the for loop to start at 1 and then change if to : if (inputValues[i - 1] >= inputValues[i])

Answer (score 2):

When your second-to-last `inputValues` element is not less than the last `inputValues` element, `inputValues[i+1]` is evaluated for the final `i` value (i.e., `inputValues.Length - 1`), that results in `i + 1 == inputValues.Length` and an index out of bounds exception.  What you need to do is handle the special case of working with the final element of `inputValues`.  One way to do so is to add such a test to that first `if` condition:

```
var nextOffset = i + 1;

if( inputValues.Length == nextOffset
    || inputValues[i] >= inputValues[nextOffset] )
{
    inputValuesAfter[i] = inputValues[i];
}
else // `if` condition isn't needed here
{
    inputValuesAfter[i] = inputValues[nextOffset] - inputValues[i];
    ++i;
}
```